# #flink different operators transfer messages use MQ

Tags: apache-flink

I saw that the link will use kafka for MQ in order to replay for failure, and does it use memory MQ when transfer message in different operators?

Answer (score 1):

Flink does not necessarily use Kafka as an input message queue, but has out of the box support for it. This source is suggested to be used in case of exactly once processing is a requirement for your job.

As for transferring messages in between Flink operators that is a completly different system and is not connected to fault tolerance in this sense.